# Where can I find some PPT files about China technology transactions and patent licensing？

Tags: ppt, transactions

I'm studying some legal issues in China technology transcations and patent licensing, and it would be very helpful for me if somebody could provide some PPT information on related aspects. Thank you, everyone.

Comment: This site works best if you ask a specific question about patents and patenting. Licensing questions are specifically off topic. Please edit the question or it may be closed.

Comment: What does PPT mean?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I believe PPT refers to PowerPoint files.